# uncountability proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the proof that the set of all sequences whose elements are 0 and 1 if we replace the set of reals with the set of natural numbers wouldn't that lead to the same contradiction that N is a proper subset of itself ?
thank you

Comment: Can you post the proof here and make the question more clear?

Comment: You mean that you want to represent each natural number by a binary sequence and apply Cantor's diagonal argument?

Comment: The number of digits in the decimal expansion of (all but certain rational) the reals are infinitely long, while every natural number has only finitely many digits.

Comment: yes Alex i want to do that , excuse my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part of Cantor's diagonal proof is that the infinite sequence you construct is an element that *should've been on the list*. All natural numbers are finite in length, and they don't have any digits after the decimal point. Therefore, an infinitely long "counterexample", such as the one Cantor's diagonal argument would give, is not a valid number in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

No. The important part of the proof involving the reals occurs with the digits that occur after the decimal point. Change one of those digits and you still have a real number.

All integers, have nothing but zeros after the decimal point. Change one of those digits, and you no longer have an integer.